# How to Search Inserted Data with Edit Text

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-search

> RecordListActivity.Java

```
//        query 
String select = "Select name, phone from RECORD Where(name like " + "'%name%'" +
                ")";
            Cursor cursor2 = mSQLiteHelper.searchData(select);
            if (cursor2.getCount() > 0 ){
                Toast.makeText(RecordListActivity.this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

> // SearchView

```
mSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.d("data", charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence2, int i, int i1, int i2) {



            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

> database

```
public Cursor searchData(String sql2){

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql2,null);


    }
```

> Model

```
private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public Model(int id, String name, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
```

> my goal is to search the listview by phrases. When a keyword is entered in the search (EditText), I want the listview to be filtered accordingly. I already have the EditText ready there, while, I am new that's why don't know how to do that, please help me? thanks

> Search(Edittext), it takes keyword but doesn't show what I have given in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code (for onTextChanged callback) can display contacts by name:

```
String select = "SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE name LIKE '"+charSequence2+"%'";
Cursor cursor = mSQLiteHelper.searchData(select);

mList.clear();
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
   int id = cursor.getInt(0);
   String name = cursor.getString(1);
   String phone = cursor.getString(2);
   mList.add(new Model(id,name,phone));
}

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I have edited With Model. can you see? @Leonid

Comment: @imtiazeemel Yes, try this code in onTextChanged

Comment: it won't give me the search result or input which i give

Comment: @imtiazeemel You must enter the exact same value for the contact name (which already exists) with the same letter case

Comment: I put exact same contact name with the same letter case but it won't show. when I type in the search option whole data vanish and not showing any searching data. @leonid. https://github.com/Imtiaz16041997/ContactSaveSQLite  (you can check it there "search problem 3")  i last commited

Comment: @imtiazeemel Oh sorry, i edited code, try again

Comment: Nothing happend. still are the same

Comment: Pushed* @Leonid

Comment: as my reputation is decrease that's why I cannot reply there. yes now uninstalled it again install it. it works. thanks

Comment: @imtiazeemel I am glad to help!

Comment: Thanks, by the way, is it possible to make it more dynamic like alphabetically (like if i put a it shows me the first value of a listed all name)

Comment: Thanks, Buddy! I also tried it but the wrong query. thank you solved my mistakes

Comment: Are you here? I have a problem to share with you @Leonid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235905/discussion-between-ibnul-imtiaz-and-leonid).